# How to push JSON Object in Array field of parse server

Tags: javascript, json, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

i am trying to push or append the json object in my array field of collection but i am getting this error "error: Error generating response. ParseError { code: 101, message: 'Object not found.' } code=101, message=Object not found.".

I am sharing my cloud code.
Parse Server - 2.3.8
Nodejs - 6.10.2
Mongodb - 3.4.

```
var Offer = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend(GameConstants.OFFER));
        Offer.select("collected");
        Offer.equalTo(GameConstants.OBJECT_ID, inputData.offer_id);
        Offer.first({
            success: function (offer) {
                if (typeof offer !== 'undefined') {                    
                    var collected = offer.get(GameConstants.COLLECTED);                    
                    collected.push({user_id: inputData.user_id, date_time: new Date()});                                        
                    offer.set(GameConstants.COLLECTED, collected);//{user_id: inputData.user_id, date_time: new Date()}
                    offer.save(null, {
                        success: function (offer) {
                            var GameUser = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend(GameConstants.GAME_USERS));
                            GameUser.select("coins", "collected_offer");
                            GameUser.equalTo(GameConstants.OBJECT_ID, inputData.user_id);
                            GameUser.first({
                                success: function (gameUser) {
                                    if (typeof gameUser !== 'undefined') {
                                        gameUser.increment(GameConstants.COINS, inputData.coins);
                                        gameUser.addUnique(GameConstants.COLLECTED_OFFERS, {offer_id: inputData.offer_id, offer_coins: inputData.coins, date_time: new Date()});
                                        gameUser.save(null, {
                                            success: function (gameUser) {
                                                callback(null, 1);
                                            },
                                            error: function (error) {
                                                callback(error);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        callback(null, 2);
                                    }
                                },
                                error: function (error) {
                                    callback(error);
                                }
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (error) {
                            callback(error);
                        }
                    })
                } else {
                    callback(null, 2);
                }
            },
            error: function (error) {
                //Error
                callback(error);
            }
        });
```

Please help me where i am going wrong.  How can i push my custom json objects in array field of mongodb using parse server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@julien-kode.  I don't have a complete answer for you (yet) but I have a suggestion that might help. You are using the old style success error functions.  A huge problem with this style of async coding is that it is easy for errors to get 'eaten'.  Instead, you want to catch the end of the chain.  So here's a re-write of your function.  I may have missed a little here since I don't have enough info to write a working test, but hopefully you get the idea and we can move the ball forward to a solution?

```
const Offer = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend(GameConstants.OFFER))
  .select("collected");
  .equalTo(GameConstants.OBJECT_ID, inputData.offer_id);
  .first()
  .then((offer) => {
    if (typeof offer !== 'undefined') {                    
      const collected = offer.get(GameConstants.COLLECTED); // << -- is Array.isArray(collected) === true ????    
      collected.push({ user_id: inputData.user_id, date_time: new Date() });                                        
      offer.set(GameConstants.COLLECTED, collected); 
      return offer.save(); // <<-- note how i am returning functions that result in promises -- this is the magic!
    } else {
      return callback(null, 2);
    }
  })
  .then((offer) => {
    return new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend(GameConstants.GAME_USERS)) // <-- whoa, we're returning the promise that results from the first() call.  cool.
      .select("coins", "collected_offer");
      .equalTo(GameConstants.OBJECT_ID, inputData.user_id);
      .first()
  })
  .then((gameUser) => {
    if (typeof gameUser !== 'undefined') {
        gameUser.increment(GameConstants.COINS, inputData.coins);
        gameUser.addUnique(GameConstants.COLLECTED_OFFERS, {offer_id: inputData.offer_id, offer_coins: inputData.coins, date_time: new Date()});
        return gameUser.save().then(() => callback(null, 1)) // a single line function with no {} will return the result of the expression....
    } else {
        return callback(null, 2);
    }
  })
  .catch(callback); <-- this is the same as .catch((error) => callback(error));
```